# Как мне увидеть весь ul, не увеличивая длину таблицы?

Tags: css

На фотке то, чего я хочу добиться [image: На фотке то, чего я хочу добиться]
А вот ссылка на нынешнюю разметку: [вот](https://jsfiddle.net/kotcich/5od80jsq/79/)

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <table>
      <tr><th>some</th></tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="ul-wrap">
              <ul>
                <li>sslmdsfmlsdkkvfldkf</li>
                <li>sslmdsfmlsdkkvfldkf</li>
                <li>sslmdsfmlsdkkvfldkf</li>
                <li>sslmdsfmlsdkkvfldkf</li>
                <li>sslmdsfmlsdkkvfldkf</li>
                <li>sslmdsfmlsdkkvfldkf</li>
                <li>sslmdsfmlsdkkvfldkf</li>
              </ul>
             </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, правильно ли я сориентировался по Вашей картинке, но попробуйте добавить какую-то высоту для элемента `div` с классом `ul-wrap`, например, **400px**.

За счет того, что списку `ul` задано абсолютное позиционирование, его родителю `ul-wrap` тяжело подстроить высоту под него:

```
.ul-wrap {
  z-index: 5;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Нет, от этого расширился главный враппер.

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант "конвертировать" положение элемента из абсолютного в фиксированное:

```js
[].slice.apply(document.getElementsByClassName("ul-wrap")).forEach(el => {
  const clientRect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  el.style.position = "fixed";
  el.style.left = clientRect.left + "px";
  el.style.top = clientRect.top + "px";
});
```

Фиксированный элемент будет по DOM-у находиться всё там же, но отображаться будет вне устанавливаемых ему рамок.

С помощью функции `Element.getBoundingClientRect` получается размещение элемента относительно окна. Затем полученные значения используются для позиционирования элемента относительно окна фиксированно.